# TypeError: cone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

Tags: python

I am writing a program that calculates the volume of a cone given the diameter and height but I keep getting this

```
TypeError: cone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

How do I fix this?

```
def main():
    measure = measurement()
    vol = cone(measure)

    print("\nThe volume of the cone is,", "%0.2f" % (vol))

def measurement():
    diameter = eval(input("Enter the diameter of the cones base:"))
    height = eval(input("Enter the height of the cone:"))
    return diameter, height

def cone(diameter, height):
    pi = 3.14
    radius = diameter / 2
    volume = (pi * (radius**2) * height) / 3
    return volume

main()
```

Comment: Some of the code looks like it's written for Python 3; are you actually using Python 2.7? In Python 2.x you'd probably be getting a `TypeError` on the `eval()` before you even got to the code where you're getting the error you're asking about. Also, the `print()` call looks like it's Python 3 style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split out the two values returned by `measurement`. You have two options:

1. Use tuple assignment and pass the two results to `cone`:

   ```
   diameter, height = measurement()
   vol = cone(diameter, height)
   ```

   Python expects `measurement()` to return two values in a sequence now and will assign those two values to `diameter` and `height`, respectively, before passing those two values separately to `cone()`.
2. Use argument expansion; this asks Python to apply all values in a sequence as separate arguments:

   ```
   measure = measurement()
   vol = cone(*measure)
   ```

   Note the `*` before the `measure` argument.

As for your `measurement()` function: you don't need to use `eval()`; it poses a security risk. Instead, use `float()` to interpret user input as real numbers:

```
def measurement():
    diameter = float(input("Enter the diameter of the cones base:"))
    height = float(input("Enter the height of the cone:"))
    return diameter, height
```

Also see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for more advanced user-input techniques.

Comment: He's using Python 3, as evidenced by his `print()` calls, so there's no `raw_input()`

Comment: @kindall: the OP tagged the question with `python-2.7` (I added the `python` tag). Loads of beginner Python programmers use `print` as if it is a function in Python 2, and it happens to work most of the time.

Comment: If he was using Python 2.x, though, he'd be getting a `TypeError` on the `eval()` of an integer input before even getting to the place where he's getting an error. I think the tag must be incorrect.

Comment: @kindall or they've been entering numbers with quotes around them all this time. Why not ask the OP by commenting on the question?

Comment: sorry, i am not using python 2.7 there is no raw_input but your first suggestion did work, thank you.

Comment: @JohnDias right; your initial tagging suggested that you did; I'll update that part of my answer.